# Prevent $('img').click triggered for several times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to prevent the confirm message being prompted for several times, thanks in advance!

javascript

```
$('img.delete').click(function () {         
    if(confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?")){
        //Do something...
    }
});
```

html

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="delete" src="/images/delete.gif"><input value="708" type="hidden"></td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="delete" src="/images/delete.gif"><input value="595" type="hidden"></td>
        <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="delete" src="/images/delete.gif"><input value="19" type="hidden"></td>
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "several times"?

Comment: How is it triggered multiple times? Surely, if they click yes in the `confirm`, you are removing the row - therefore that link cannot possibly be clicked again.

Comment: Refer to the html code, the confirm message "This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?" has been prompted for 3 times.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Clicking on a given image will only display the popup once...

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Do you mean you want the user prompted the first time they click a delete, and never again if they click another delete?

Comment: Yup, this is my expected result too, and actually it prompts me 3 times...

Comment: @user1439709 are you sure ?  It is pretty useless behaviour, when only one button works in session

Comment: your question unclear.. please edit and make sense

Comment: Thank you guys so much for concerning to this question! @Jack has provided the solution for me, please check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you apply the click handler multiple times; this is not visible from the code that you have posted, but it's definitely the cause.

If you run `$('img.delete').click(fn)` multiple times, it doesn't overwrite the previous click handler; rather, it adds another handler. Afterwards, when `img.delete` is clicked, ALL registered handlers get called in succession, resulting in one popup window followed by another.

It should be remedied by calling `.unbind()` first; doing so will effectively replace the previous click handler(s) by a new one.

```
$('img.delete')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function () {         
        if(confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?")){
            //Do something...

            // remove the image here I guess?
        }
    });
```

But it would be better if you could hunt the root cause down as well.

Comment: Thanks man! You are fully understanding my question, and your solution is really working great for me. Would you please explain more why do I need unbind here?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by unbinding in jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('img.delete').click(function () {         
        if(confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?")){
            //Do something...
        }
        $('img.delete').unbind('click');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, that's pretty much what that was made for.

```
 $('img.delete'.one('click',function () {         
            if(confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?")){
                //Do something...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Great answer, but you dont need the `each`. `$('img.delete').one(..)` would suffice

Comment: @Jamiec no that is not true, if you do that it will only work on one img.delete and not all of them

Comment: Doom scenario: click 'delete' -> click 'no' -> click 'delete' .... awww, no more popup :(

Comment: @Jack . Thats what he wanted. question states. "how to prevent the confirm message being prompted for several times"

Comment: I didnt dv but probably because you missed the name of the event from your  call to `one`. It should be `.one('click',function(){...})`. Also on my point above, the `each` **is** useless. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub4SA/

Comment: I wish the downvoter would remove their dv now. This is the best answer by far.

Comment: @Jamiec The downvote stays, because `.one()` doesn't solve the root cause AND introduces another issue, described by my "doom scenario".

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about this, you can be sure to not have event handler after click:

```
var confirm_me=function () {
    if(confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?")){
        //Do something...
    }
    //restore event handler
    $(this).one('click',confirm_me);
    //prevent event propagation
    return false;
    }

//BE sure that you not do that in loop. if possible do - see second code
$('img.delete').one('click',confirm_me);
```

---

other case:

```
var confirm_me=function () {
     var t=$(this);
    //check processing flag
    if (t.data('processing')) return false;
    //Set processing flag
    t.data('processing',1);


    if(confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?")){
        //Do something...
    }

    //restore event handler
    t.one('click',confirm_me);
    //remove processing flag
    t.data('processing',0);
    //prevent event propagation
    return false;
    }

$('img.delete').one('click',confirm_me);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it , it is verified by me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var check = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('img.delete').click(function () {
        if (check != true) {
            if (confirm("This selected record will be deleted. Are you sure?"))
                check = true;
        }
        else {
            alert('you have deleted one');
        }
        });
     });
</script>
```